# Match a name to the best fitting email using regex

Tags: python, regex, email

def email_matcher(emails_file, names_file):
    matches = {}

```
with open(names_file, 'r') as names:
    for i in names:
        with open(emails_file, 'r') as emails:
            first = i[:(i.index(' '))]
            pattern2 = i[0]
            last = i[::-1].strip()
            last = last[0:(last.index(' '))][::-1]
            for j in emails:
                if re.search(first,j):
                    matches[i] = j
                elif re.search(last,j):
                    matches[i] = j
                else:
                    matches[i] = 'nothing found'
return matches
pass
```

This is my code so far, i know it does not work and i get the thing to be no matches found. The goal is to look through all the emails for the best matching email to a name. I have no idea how to make the pattern for regex, i tried looking at the documentation but idk the exact thing to do. What i want to do is check different things in the most accurate order

1 - check if first name last name and middle name are in email
2- check if first name and last name are in email
3 - check if first name last initial
4 - check if first initial last name
5 - check if first name
6 - check if last name

Would it be multiple searches throughout the email with like 6 different regex searches, or is there a way to do one search on every email and see if it hits any of the groups in the pattern

Right now in my code I just have a first name and last name searching that gets none right at all.

Adding emails

Mary Williams - mary.williams@gmail.com

Charles Deanna West - charles.west@yahoo.com

Jacob Jessica Andrews - jandrews@hotmail.com

Javier Daisy Sparks - javier.sparks@gmail.com

Paula A. Graham - graham@gmail.com ( could not find the best matching one, none had paula. there are multiple paulas and grahams in the names list as well)

Jasmine Sherman - jherman@hotmail.com

Matthew Foster - matthew.foster@gmail.com

Ernest Michael Bowman - ernest.bowman@gmail.com

Chad Hernandez - hernandez@gmail.com

So i just looked through all of these and it seems the pattern is firstinitiallastname, firstname.lastname, or lastname@email. The thing is though there are a shit ton of names and even more emails so I dont know the general case. But I feel like it would suffice if i looked for firstname.lastname@email, then firstinitiallastname@email,then middleinitallastname@email, and then the worst case would just be lastname@email?

Comment: what format are your names and emails in? Please give us some examples of both `("john smith", john.smith@site.com)`, `("john smith", john.s@site.com)`, `("john smith", j.smith@site.com)`

Comment: @Addison I just finished adding a couple examples. I control Fd to find the best ones I could see

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that you can do it without regex but by using a fuzzy matching system called Levenshtein.

First, separate the email from the domain so that the @something.com is in a different column.

Next, it sounds like you're describing an algorithm for fuzzy matching called Levenshtein distance. You can use a module designed for this, or perhaps write a custom one:

```
import numpy as np
def levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(s, t, ratio_calc = False):
    """ levenshtein_ratio_and_distance:
        Calculates levenshtein distance between two strings.
        If ratio_calc = True, the function computes the
        levenshtein distance ratio of similarity between two strings
        For all i and j, distance[i,j] will contain the Levenshtein
        distance between the first i characters of s and the
        first j characters of t
    """
    # Initialize matrix of zeros
    rows = len(s)+1
    cols = len(t)+1
    distance = np.zeros((rows,cols),dtype = int)

    # Populate matrix of zeros with the indeces of each character of both strings
    for i in range(1, rows):
        for k in range(1,cols):
            distance[i][0] = i
            distance[0][k] = k

    # Iterate over the matrix to compute the cost of deletions,insertions and/or substitutions    
    for col in range(1, cols):
        for row in range(1, rows):
            if s[row-1] == t[col-1]:
                cost = 0 # If the characters are the same in the two strings in a given position [i,j] then the cost is 0
            else:
                # In order to align the results with those of the Python Levenshtein package, if we choose to calculate the ratio
                # the cost of a substitution is 2. If we calculate just distance, then the cost of a substitution is 1.
                if ratio_calc == True:
                    cost = 2
                else:
                    cost = 1
            distance[row][col] = min(distance[row-1][col] + 1,      # Cost of deletions
                                 distance[row][col-1] + 1,          # Cost of insertions
                                 distance[row-1][col-1] + cost)     # Cost of substitutions
    if ratio_calc == True:
        # Computation of the Levenshtein Distance Ratio
        Ratio = ((len(s)+len(t)) - distance[row][col]) / (len(s)+len(t))
        return Ratio
    else:
        # print(distance) # Uncomment if you want to see the matrix showing how the algorithm computes the cost of deletions,
        # insertions and/or substitutions
        # This is the minimum number of edits needed to convert string a to string b
        return "The strings are {} edits away".format(distance[row][col])
```

Now you can get a numerical value for how similar they are. You'll still need to establish a cutoff as to what number is acceptable to you.

```
Str1 = "Apple Inc."
Str2 = "apple Inc"
Distance = levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower())
print(Distance)
Ratio = levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower(),ratio_calc = True)
print(Ratio)
```

There are other similarity algorithms other than Levenshtein. You might try Jaro-Winkler, or perhaps Trigram.

I got this code from: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out that the pattern works for everything